# Implementation of multithreading using concurrent.future in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have written a python code which convert raw data (STM Microscope) into png format and it run perfectly on my Macbook Pro.

Below is the simplified Python Code:

```
for root, dirs, file in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        fpath = path +'/'+ dir
        os.chdir(fpath)
        spaths=savepath +'/'+ dir
        if os.path.exists(spaths) ==False:
           os.mkdir(spaths)

         for files in glob.glob("*.sm4"):
             for file in files:     
                 data_conv (files, file, spaths)
```

But it does take 30 - 40 mins for100 files.

Now, I wanted to reduce processing time using multithreading technique (using “concurrent future” library). Was trying to modify python code using YouTube video on “Python Threading Tutorial” as an example.

But I have to pass too many arguments such as “root”, “dirs.”, “file”  in the executor.map() method. I don’t know how to resolve this further.

Below this the simplified multithreading Python code

```
def raw_data (root, dirs, file):
    for dir in dirs:
        fpath = path +'/'+ dir
        os.chdir(fpath)
        spaths=savepath +'/'+ dir
        if os.path.exists(spaths)==False:
            os.mkdir(spaths)

        for files in glob.glob("*.sm4"):
            for file in files:
                data_conv(files, file, spaths)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
     executor.map(raw_data, root, dirs, file)
```

```
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

Any suggestion is appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: If the workload is CPU bound you should use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` instead since Python threads will not run concurrently due to the GIL. Do you need to wrap your call to `executor.map` with `for root, dirs, file in os.walk(path):`?

Comment: Sorry I am not an expert here, I don't know what is GIL. But, I need to reduce the processing time using by Multithreading or multiprocessing.
.............
{Do you need to wrap your call to executor.map with for root, dirs, file in os.walk(path):?}    YES

Comment: Unless you are IO bound (lots of network/API calls, writing/reading files) multiprocessing is your best bet. The GIL prevents threads from running concurrently (at the same time)

Comment: Any example or suggestion would be helpful to understand to implement the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice Iain Shelvington & Thenoneman.

[Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) does reduces the clutter I was having in my code.

"ProcessPoolExecutor" worked in my CPU intense function.

```
  with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(raw_data, os.walk(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Iain Shelvington pointed out, `data_conv` seems like a CPU intensive function, therefore you won't notice improvement with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, use `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Second, you have to pass parameters to each instance of function call, i.e. pass lists of arguments to `raw_data`. Assuming `root` and `file` are the same and dirs is a list:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(raw_data, [root]*len(dirs), dirs, [file]*len(dirs)
    for result in results:
        # Collect you results
```

**As a sidenote**, you may find working with filesystem more pleasing with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which is also built-in since Python 3.4